# Leer tupla de enteros desde caja de texto

Tags: haskell

Estoy usando Haskell online y lo que quiero es que el compilador tome el valor de una tupla de la caja de texto stdin y evalué la expresión. Por ejemplo, considerando la función `suma`, que suma dos enteros, con los valores en tupla `(5,9)` me devolvería 14.

Acá se define la función suma, que toma una tupla y devuelve la suma de los elementos de esta.

```
suma::(Int,Int) -> Int
suma (a,b) = a + b
```

En el main

```
main = do 
n <- getLine
t <- getLine
putStrLn (show (suma (read n, read t)))
```

Al ingresar la tupla `(5,9)` en la caja de entrada, el programa tira el siguiente error:

```
Main: <stdin>: hGetLine: end of file
```

¿Es un error de paréntesis o hay que asignar la lectura de la cupla necesariamente a una variable?

Comment: En el cuadro de texto del editor online, a diferencia del offline, no se coloca la tupla entre paréntesis, sino los valores separados línea por línea, de lo contrario el compilador va a seguir esperando hasta que tire error <stdin>: hGetLine: end of file

Comment: El código que has puesto es para leer un número en cada línea. Nada tiene qué ver que el editor sea online u offline.

Comment: Ya pude resolver el error, no sabía que en el compilador de Haskell online (al menos el que estoy utilizando) se deben poder un número en cada línea.